# PHP application design - multi-threading?

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter, xml-rpc

I'm creating a PHP application that will simulate api calls to a server using multiple devices at timed intervals.  It will be built in CodeIgniter and the transport medium is XMLRpc.  Up to 50 devices will be represented.  Each device has a file that represents user input and a delay for making the next call.   This will be done from the one desktop machine.

Simple example with 2 simulated readers:

Reader 1

```
barcode,     delay
99000121,       9
99000121,       1
99000121,       3
99000121,       4
```

Reader 2

```
barcode,     delay
99000125,       2
99000126,       5
99000127,       6
99000121,       4
```

The application will look at Reader 1, take the barcode on line 1 and send that to the api.  Once it receives the response, it will wait 9 seconds and then make another api call.

The api calls from the 2 readers should start at the same time in the PHP application.  I'm trying to decide how to write the PHP script so this happens.  I've been looking at  [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) and multithreading.  Do you think it would be possible to create multiple threads each representing an independent device?

Any ideas on how to best write this in PHP would be very useful.  I can give further information if necessary.